# How to set the form content in same order even if minimize or maximize in C++ Builder?

Tags: forms, c++builder

In C++ Builder how can I set the form's window as resizable? Is there some property that needs to be set? I want to set the form content in same order even if minimize or maximize in C++ Builder

Comment: The question in the title is different from what you ask in the body of your post. So, what are you asking? Do you want to prevent the user from minimizing the form with the minimize button, or do you want to prevent the OS from minimizing the form? And what do you mean with from content in same order?

Comment: updated the body. please check now.

Comment: But why do you think that the form content changes order if you minimize or restore?

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a [mre]

Comment: It's fact and very simple logic if someone maximize the form, there will be space it will not be dynamically maintained like earlier.
So my question is very simple how can we fix dynamically like earlier even after maximizing.

Is there any configurations settings or something else?

Comment: If I get it now, you want all components on the form to maintain their  relative position as you resize the form. Then I still need to ask you, do you also want that the components maintain their size also?

Comment: You can try whether using component properties `Align` and/or `Anchor` helps you. You can also place the components on a `TGridPanel` and lock that panels sides distance to the forms borders with `Anchor` properties.

Comment: Yes,i  also want that the components maintain their size also

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference but is it a VCL or FMX application? If you just place VCL components on a form, without using `Align` or `Anchor` or any panels, do you then get the behavior you want or is it still something that isn't right?